# Unable to get Google OAuth authentication working with React Native and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to get Google OAuth working with Firebase and React Native and can't seem to get everything working together. I'm using the NPM package [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/apptailor/react-native-google-signin) to handle the Google OAuth side of things and that is working as expected. I'm running into an issue getting the user authenticated with Firebase however.

I've enabled Google Authentication on my Firebase instance according to the instructions in the Web Guide. However, when I try authenticating with the `idToken` field from the native OAuth package I always get an `INVALID_CREDENTIALS` error from Firebase. I am using the [authWithOAuthToken](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthtoken.html) method from the Firebase Web API.

I think I've tried every combination of using the Web/Android client IDs for the Firebase configuration and the `idToken` and `serverAuthCode` fields from the OAuth package but everything ends with the same error. Has anyone gotten this to work correctly?

Comment: have you any news about that ?

Answer (score 3):

This is how i did it for my app:

```
import {GoogleSignin} from 'react-native-google-signin';

const KEYS = {
    // ... // ios and web keys (i'm loading them from my server)
} 

login() {
  GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true })
   .then(() => {
      GoogleSignin.configure(KEYS)
        .then(() => {
          GoogleSignin.signIn()
            .then(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess)
            .catch(error=>{})
            .done();
        });
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
   })
}

onGoogleLoginSuccess(user) {
  var token = user.idToken;
  var provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
  var credential = provider.credential(token);
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((data)=>console.log('SUCCESS', data))
    .catch((error)=>console.log('ERROR', error));
}
```

The point is to use `signInWithCredential()` method. Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithCredential

Comment: Can you tell what is supposed to be printed on `.then((data)=>console.log('SUCCESS', data))`?