# Google Sign In with Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login with Google but it throws me this error:

> code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment"
>   message: "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."

This is the code:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

#### Aditional Information:

- "firebase": "^3.7.1"
- "react-native": "^0.42.0"
- platform: Android

any ideas?
thanks in advance!

Comment: The `signInWithPopup()` method doesn't work with React Native, only on web. Try to use `signInWithCredential()` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41014021/1206613

Comment: Thanks, I've got Google auth working so far, but firebase auth isn't working when calling signInWithCredential method.
I posted more details [here](https://github.com/davideast/firebase-react-native-sample/issues/28#issuecomment-287161708)

Answer (score 5):

First I used [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) to Sign In with Google. Follow these [steps](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md) to configure it.

Make sure you correctly [sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android/37657942#37657942) your APK (debug or release).

In `app/build.gradle` exclude `com.google.android.gms` from the dependencies that use it like so:

```
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}
```

Then link you Google token with Firebase:

```js
const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
const credential = provider.credential(token);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('SUCCESS', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
  });
```

I'm using firebase 3.7.1

This is how my dependencies look in `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    compile (project(':react-native-fcm')){
        exclude group: "com.google.firebase"
    }
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1') {
        force = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the whole `signIn()` method that has both Google signin as well as firebase signin for clarity?

Comment: @AlejandroJS Please share your whole code! I am also facing some issues this would be of great help!

Answer (score 3):

[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html)

"Headful" auth methods such as `signInWithPopup()`, `signInWithRedirect()`, `linkWithPopup()`, and `linkWithRedirect()` do not work in React Native (or Cordova, for that matter). You can still sign in or link with a federated provider by using `signInWithCredential()` with an OAuth token from your provider of choice.

Answer (score 1):

The general issue is not about changing the code with the solution, is more than we you use `npm link` the solution will be broke again, as the `npm link` will be re-adding the new line causing the error again.

`npm link` will search with regex, the current line is 
`compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){` so we need to change it to the format `compile project ("package")` and split to the next like the bracket char.
In the following way:

```
compile project(":react-native-google-signin")
{         
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}
```

so when you run `npm link`, it will detect the dependency and won't be duplicated but also the if block code will be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

I am replying late but it will be helpful for others, if you are using firebase with google sign then you must exclude some libraries and those your app gradle like that

```
 compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
 }
 compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'){
     force = true;
 }
 compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+") { // the plus allows you to use the latest version
    force = true;
 }

 compile (project(path: ':react-native-fbsdk')){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
 }
 compile(project(":react-native-firebase")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
 }
```

[This is discussion about that issue for more detail answer](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/275)

Answer (score 0):

**I find all other answers to be either incorrect or deprecated.**

**[react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/)** which is the officially recommended collection of packages that brings React Native support for all Firebase services on both Android and iOS apps.

1. Be sure to follow `Firebase Authentication` setup instructions: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage
2. Setup `Firebase Authentication` with `google-signin`: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin